# How to edit the content of dynamically added li without affecting the other elements inside of the li - jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

```js
$("#refdocs_list li").on('click', 'span[data-id="editable-list-item"]', function() {
  var $input = $('<input type="text" data-id="editable-list-item">');
  $input.val($(this).html());
  $(this).replaceWith($input);
  $input.focus();
});

$("#refdocs_list li").on('focusout', 'input[data-id="editable-list-item"]', function() {
  var $span = $('<span data-id="editable-list-item">');
  $span.html($(this).val());
  $(this).replaceWith($span);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="refdocs_list" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;">
  <li><span data-id="editable-list-item">test1</span></li>
  <li><span data-id="editable-list-item">test2</span></li>
  <li><span data-id="editable-list-item">test3</span></li>
</ul>
```

I am working on a ToDo list app and I want to make the dynamically added list items editable. When the user click on the list item I want them to be able to change the text and save it automatically once the click outside of the list item.

I am facing some challenges since I have checkbox and button elements inside the list items I am appending.

I tried the following solutions and none of them worked:

1. Using `$('.edit').editable('save.php')` - this edit the entire content of the element so the user can actually remove the button and the checkbox
2. Using `contenteditable` attribute - same result, allows the user to edit all all the elements inside the list item.
3. I tried wrapping the user input in a span and only applying the `class="edit"` to the span but this didn't work. See the CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/skarmen/pen/OJNQPQe)

I am looking for solutions that are using the jQuery Jeditable and also implementing this from scratch.

Here is my code:

```
let userInput = $('input').val().trim() 

let removeItem = '<button id="remove">x</button>'

let checkbox = '<input type="checkbox">'


$('ol').append(`<li>${checkbox} <span class="edit">${userInput}</span> ${removeItem}</li>`);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The codepen may only be reverting to original value since the ajax can't complete with relative url there. The span approach should work fine once you get the mechanics and options of `editable` plugin figured out. You would also need some identifier to send as well if you are storing server side. I haven't used that plugin for a long time but remember it is highly configurable and robust

Comment: @charlietfl - I got it working! Now I am having hard time figuring out how to save the updated content in a function as I don't want to use a server to save that info. Would you be able to provide me with an example?

Comment: You could learn to use `localStorage` and store it there. The plugin will have event callbacks you can use for updates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to help you using only the question title. First, I think what you need is to listen to events in the parent so it doesn't matter what children it has (dynamically or not), it'd work because the element will delegate to its children.

Example:

```
$('ol').on('click', 'li', () => console.log('make this editable'))
```

Then, if what you're trying to accomplish is also to replace the `li` with the one appended in the last line of your code, I recommend one of this:

1. Leave that code ON at all times but hidden for the user interface (display:none for example) and just turn ON/OFF as the user clicks. This way you won't be trapped into this situation and would offer a smothier experience to the user. Just don't forget to put proper ARIA labels and all a11y stuff like visibility.
2. Don't remove the `li` just its contents. Save it first into a variable, toggle when the user clicks with your content then go back with the saved version if the user didn't edit.

Hope it helps!